# Algorithm 14.2 Prince Computer Vision ML learning of intrinsic parameters

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

**Problem**: I need to use the algorithm 14.2 in Prince's Computer vision textbook, but I am unclear as to what T stands for in the pseudo code.

**Pseudo Code Outline**: Algorithm 14.2

ML learning of intrinsic parameters

Input : World points {wi}I i=1, image points {xi}I i=1, initial Λ

Output: Intrinsic parameters Λ \ Λ is the intrinsic matrix

```
begin 

// Main loop for alternating optimization 

for t=1 to T do 

// Compute extrinsic parameters 

[Ω,τ] = calcExtrinsic[Λ,{wi,xi}I i=1] \\Ω is the rotation matrix,τ is the translation

// Compute intrinsic parameters 

for i=1 to I do

// Compute matrix Ai 

ai = (ω1•wi + τx)/(ω3•wi + τz) 

// ωk• is kth row of Ω 

bi = (ω2•wi + τy)/(ω3•wi + τz) 

Ai = [ai,bi,1,0,0;0,0,0,bi,1]
 
end 

// Concatenate matrices and data points

x = [x1;x2;...xI] 

A = [A1;A2;...AI] 

// Compute parameters 

θ = (A^TA)−1A^Tx 

Λ = [θ1,θ2,θ3;0,θ4,θ5;0,0,1] 

end 

// Refine parameters with non-linear optimization Λ
```

**Problem**: My question is simple but crucial. What does he mean by `for t=1 to T do`? I am confused since T isn't an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The capital T is a set parameter for number iterations for alternating the iterative calculation of the 6Dof, [Ω,τ], and intrinsic camera matrix, Λ.